# How to get a reference to an Azure MSI for an app service?

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-managed-identity

I have been testing out the recently released Managed Service Identity (MSI) for Azure and have successfully created an MSI for our App Services using the ARM template approach described in the documentation here: [How to use Azure Managed Service Identity (public preview) in App Service and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-managed-service-identity)

However, I would like to grant access for the managed identity on other resources, such as a key vault. I have been able to do this through the portal, but need to be able to script it in PowerShell in order to integrate with our continuous deployment builds.

I have successfully created the access using PowerShell by executing Set-AzureRmKeyVaultAccessPolicy cmdlet. However I have only been able to do this with a hard-coded object id, manually copied and pasted from the portal once the MSI has been created.

My question is, how in PowerShell can I get a reference to the MSI's object id, so that I can grant access to it on other resources? The only examples I can find (such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/msi-howto-assign-access-powershell)), refer only to VMs and not App Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureadserviceprincipal?view=azureadps-2.0).

```
$web=Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "<name>"
$web.ObjectId
```

By default, the name is your web app name.

Update:

For OP's scenario, we could use the [template](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/blob/master/azuredeploy.json) to  get a reference to an Azure MSI.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Walter! I suspect your answer is correct, but unfortunately wasn't actually able to verify that it works, because the service principal which is executing the PowerShell scripts doesn't have permission to search the graph API. I did however discover that I was able to reference the MSI identities in my ARM deployment scripts to grant them permission to Key Vault on deployment, which negated my need to use PowerShell for this particular task at all.

Comment: For anyone else looking for information on granting a MSI access to key vault, I found my solution in the deployment script for this sample app...https://github.com/Azure-Samples/app-service-msi-keyvault-dotnet/blob/master/azuredeploy.json

Answer (score 1):

Because you deployed your resources using ARM, I'd like to add this answer as you can do it using ARM only:

1. Enable ARM template deployment for your key vault:

   ```
   {
     "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",   
     "name": "[parameters('keyVaultName')]",       
     ...
     "properties": {
       "enabledForTemplateDeployment": true,
       ...
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create the system identity:

   ```
   {
     "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
     "name": "[parameters('functionAppName')]",       
     ...
     "identity": {
       "type": "SystemAssigned"
     }
     ...
   }
   ```
3. Create an access policy:

   ```
   {
     "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
     "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies",
     "name": "[concat(parameters('keyVaultName'), '/add')]",
     "properties": {
       "accessPolicies": [
         {
           "tenantId": "[parameters('tenantId')]",
           "objectId": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName')), '2018-02-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]",
           "permissions": {
             "secrets": [ "get" ]
           }
         }
       ]
     },
     "dependsOn": [
       "[resourceId('Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults', parameters('keyVaultName'))]",
       "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('functionAppName'))]"
     ]
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

With the latest AzureRM Module (6.13.1)

```
$AppProp = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $name
```

Write-Output `$AppProp.Identity`

This Identity property gives all the required details about MSI.

```
Type        : SystemAssigned

TenantId    : c764619f-8856-4a9f-a81e-eeb0c3f93592

PrincipalId : 3d317dfe-5589-4aae-94a4-51f1776979a7
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the Azure RM PowerShell Commandlets than you can use:

```
$(Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString $Name | where {$_.DisplayName -eq $Name}).Id
```

The where part is to make sure you have the specific SP and not multiple results **starting** with the same name.

Edit:
Even this above could result in multiple values. An even better solution is to filter further like this:

```
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal -SearchString $Name | where {($_.DisplayName -eq $Name) -and ($_.ServicePrincipalNames -match "https://identity.azure.net")}
```